My Vue API client retrieves required data from the host and prepares an output .csv file with correct headers & IDs, but the retrieved data is missing
Here is my code: https://github.com/d0uble-happiness/discogsCSV
App.vue
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click="downloadSampleInputFile">Download basic sample file</button>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button @click="createSampleInputFile">Download random sample file</button>
    </div>

    <div>
        <FileUpload @file="setFile" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <p v-for="row of data" :key="row">
            {{ row }}
        </p>
    </div>

</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import FileUpload from '@/components/FileUpload.vue';
import { fetchRelease, parseCsvToArray } from '@/parser';
import { prepareDownload } from './components/PrepareDownload';
import { downloadSampleInputFile } from './components/DownloadSampleInputFile';
import { createSampleInputFile } from './components/CreateSampleInputFile';

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'App',
    components: {
        FileUpload
    },
    data() {
        return {
            data: null as null | string[],
            createSampleInputFile,
            downloadSampleInputFile
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async setFile(file: File) {
            this.data = await parseCsvToArray(file)
            console.log(this.data)
        },
        async fetchReleases(idList: string[]) {
            try {
                const data = await fetchRelease(idList)
                console.log('Fetched data from Discogs', data)
                return data
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('Failed fetching releases', err)
            }
        },
        async downloadCSV(data: any[]) {
            prepareDownload(data)
        },
    },
    watch: {
        data(data) {
            this.fetchReleases(data)
            this.downloadCSV(data)
        }
    },
});
</script>

FetchRelease.ts
import { DiscogsClient } from '@lionralfs/discogs-client'
import { processReleaseData } from './ProcessReleaseData'

export default {
  name: 'FetchRelease',
  methods: {
    fetchRelease
  }
}

const db = new DiscogsClient().database()

async function fetchRelease(releaseId: string): Promise<any[] | { error: string }> {
  try {
    const { data } = await db.getRelease(releaseId)
    return processReleaseData(releaseId, data)
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      error: `Release with ID ${releaseId} does not exist`
    }
  }
}

ProcessReleaseData.ts
import { type GetReleaseResponse } from '@lionralfs/discogs-client/lib/types'

export default {
  name: 'ProcessReleaseData',
  methods: {
    processReleaseData
  }
}

export function processReleaseData(releaseId: string, data: GetReleaseResponse) {
  const { country = 'Unknown', genres = [], styles = [], year = 'Unknown' } = data
  const artists = data.artists?.map?.((artist) => artist.name)
  const barcode = data.identifiers
    .filter((id) => id.type === 'Barcode')
    .map((barcode) => barcode.value)
  const catno = data.labels.map((catno) => catno.catno)
  const delimiter = '|'
  const descriptions = data.formats.map((descriptions) => descriptions.descriptions)
  const format = data.formats.map((format) => format.name)
  const labels = data.labels.map((label) => label.name)
  const qty = data.formats.map((format) => format.qty)
  const tracklist = data.tracklist.map((track) => track.title)
  const uniqueCatno = [...new Set(catno)]
  const uniqueLabels = [...new Set(labels)]
  const formattedBarcode = barcode.join(delimiter)
  const formattedCatNo = uniqueCatno.join(delimiter)
  const formattedGenres = genres.join(delimiter)
  const formattedLabels = uniqueLabels.join(delimiter)
  const formattedStyles = styles.join(delimiter)
  const formattedTracklist = tracklist.join(delimiter)
  const preformattedDescriptions = descriptions.toString().replace('"', '""').replace(/,/g, ', ')
  const formattedDescriptions = '"' + preformattedDescriptions + '"'
  const formattedData: any[] = [
    releaseId,
    artists,
    format,
    qty,
    formattedDescriptions,
    formattedLabels,
    formattedCatNo,
    country,
    year,
    formattedGenres,
    formattedStyles,
    formattedBarcode,
    formattedTracklist
  ]

  return formattedData
}

PrepareDownload.ts
import { ROW_NAMES } from './RowNames'

export default {
  name: 'PrepareDownload',
  methods: {
    prepareDownload
  }
}

export function prepareDownload(data: any[]) {
  const csvContent =
    'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' +
    ROW_NAMES.join(',') +
    '\n' +
    data.map((e) => e.join(',')).join('\n')
  const encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent)
  const link = document.createElement('a')
  link.setAttribute('href', encodedUri)
  link.setAttribute('download', 'my_data.csv')
  document.body.appendChild(link) // Required for Firefox
  link.click()
}

Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/tyq1yFm.png
The data highlighted in the console should be in the highlighted cells, but all such data is missing, as you can see. Any pointers to solve this please? TIA.

It looks like you aren't setting this.data to the content you get in fetchReleases().
    async fetchReleases(idList: string[]) {
        try {
            const data = await fetchRelease(idList)
            console.log('Fetched data from Discogs', data)
            this.data = data      // <--- this shows data in the view
            return data
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Failed fetching releases', err)
        }
    },

I'm not sure exactly how things should be working in your flow, but I at least see data if this.data is assigned.
For what it's worth, I generally consider the Composition API (<script setup>) to be easier to read and maintain than the older Options API. In your case specifically, there's a lot of use of the data identifier and the Composition API would clean that up a bit.
Updated solution:
In your code, data was used for input and output, and it wasn't obvious what the expected input format should be. On the assumption your sample file with 5 numbers (no header, not really a CSV) I migrated to the Composition API, and separated data into inputData and outputData. This makes is easier to watch them for their distinct purposes.
You could get rid of the use of inputData completely if you want to just use the input in setFile() but the basic sample data doesn't give me much to go on. The "random sample" didn't work from your repo.
App.vue
<script setup lang="ts">

import { ref, watch } from 'vue'
import FileUpload from '@/components/FileUpload.vue';
import { fetchRelease, parseCsvToArray } from '@/parser';
import { prepareDownload } from './components/PrepareDownload';
import { downloadSampleInputFile } from './components/DownloadSampleInputFile';
import { createSampleInputFile } from './components/CreateSampleInputFile';

const inputData = ref<string[]>([])
const outputData = ref<null | any[]>(null)

async function setFile(file: File) {
  inputData.value = await parseCsvToArray(file)
  console.log(inputData.value)
}

async function fetchReleases(idList: string[]) {
  try {
    const data = await fetchRelease(idList)
    console.log('Fetched data from Discogs', data)
    outputData.value = data
    return data
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Failed fetching releases', err)
  }
}

async function downloadCSV(data: any[]) {
  prepareDownload(data)
}

watch(inputData, newValue => {
  fetchReleases(newValue)
})

watch(outputData, newValue => {
  if (newValue) {
    downloadCSV(newValue)
  }
})

</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="downloadSampleInputFile">Download basic sample file</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button @click="createSampleInputFile">Download random sample file</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <FileUpload @file="setFile" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <p v-for="row of outputData" :key="row">
      {{ row }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

Modified this line in parser.ts
export async function fetchRelease(releaseIds: string[]): Promise<any[]> {


I tried that, but I got "Type 'any[] | { error: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string[] | null'.
Type '{ error: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.ts(2322)". Will consider what you said about the Composition API, thanks.

2/ I solved the previous error I mentioned by checking data is an array in my code. But unfortunately the data is still absent from the output file.

The file is being downloaded twice. My browser was allowing the first one, but blocking the second. After changing the site settings in the browser, I noticed the first file was always empty, and the second had data. I have edited my answer to include a flow that works here with one download.

Ah, nice, thanks Matt! Wow, that's quite a big difference!  It's not trivial for me to understand all these changes. The most confusing bits to me are ref<string[]>([]) and ref<null | any[]>(null). Anyway, I'll try to study these improvements. Thanks again.
